Is there an example that shows that a LLM is completely wrong on a biblical interpretation?
The usage of LLMs for biblical interpretations/hermeneutics will probably spread and increase.
So I was wondering if there are examples where an LLM is completely wrong and not just inaccurate.
Inaccuracies: The overall answer is correct but single details are wrong or debatable.
E.g.:

citations that are a verse off
Bible quotes where a single word (less important word like an article) is different from the cited verse.
the days in genesis refer to 24hour days (without also mentioning different interpretations)
killing vs murder in the 10 commandments

Completely Wrong: The Overall answer is wrong not only a single detail.
E.g.

completely hallucinated Bible verses.
When Jesus threw the shopkeeper out of the temple, he went on a killing spree.

Another example that can either be seen as inaccurate or completely wrong:
Question: What does the term "Messiah" mean in the context of the Old Testament?

The term "Messiah" in the Old Testament exclusively refers to Jesus Christ, who was prophesied to come and save humanity from sin.


From those examples it could be better to say it's "not even wrong"!

@curiousdannii fair.

It might help if you explained the meaning of LLM.

@RevelationLad https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_language_model TL;DR: The Technology behind a service like ChatGPT

@DavidD I see LLM as part of a toolset for hermeneutics. Of course, LLMs come with their risks and problems. Because of that, I think it is part of a hermeneutical approach, that should be explored and discussed here, because there is no SE that can explore and correct LLMs in regards to biblical hermeneutics.

To me this is very literally 'meta' - it's asking a question about other questions and answers, so I've moved it over.

Here's ChatGPT explanation of how to arrive at an answer.

When you ask a question, I analyze the context and use my knowledge to generate a relevant response. I consider the information provided in the conversation, any user-uploaded images, and predefined tools at my disposal. If I need to search the web, I use Bing Search to find accurate and up-to-date information. My goal is to provide helpful and informative answers!

I further ask;
How do ChatGPT determine which information is helpful?

ChatGPT determines the helpfulness of information based on context, relevance, and accuracy. It considers the user’s query, existing conversation, and any available knowledge. The goal is to provide useful and meaningful answers!

How do ChatGPT measure the helpfulness of a piece of information, compare to another?

ChatGPT assesses the helpfulness of information by considering context, relevance, and accuracy. It evaluates how well a response aligns with the user’s query, existing conversation, and available knowledge. Comparing two pieces of information involves weighing their suitability and applicability to the specific context.

According to its explanation, the answer chosen by the language model will likely be the most popular information available on the web.
If a language model provides completely inaccurate information, the fault may not lie with the model itself, but with the sources it has been trained on. Thus, the main question arises: why were so many people exposed to incorrect information? Could it be that the readers who comment on these pieces of information are also misinformed?

"will likely be the most popular information available" LLMs are also quite good to present multiple opinions and viewpoints, even unpopular ones and even sometimes warns about them or presents consequences. But in general a good answer, except it does not give an example for an LLM answer that is completely wrong.

Thus far LLM has refrained from presenting its own opinion. Typically, Its responses include references to the original sources from which the answers are derived.

The reason is multi-faceted but the main reason is the LLM's like ChatGPT does not actually convey any meaning and is not motivated by the Holy Spirit.  Specifically, LLM's cannot grasp the significance of the following verse:

John 16:13, 14 - However, when the Spirit of Truth comes, He will guide you into all truth. For He will not speak on His own, but He will speak what He hears, and He will declare to you what is to come. He will glorify Me by taking from what is Mine and disclosing it to you. 15Everything that belongs to the Father is Mine. That is why I said that the Spirit will take from what is Mine and disclose it to you.
John 5:39 - You pore over the Scriptures because you presume that by them you possess eternal life. These are the very words that testify about Me,
Luke 24:27 - And beginning with Moses and all the Prophets, He explained to them what was written in all the Scriptures about Himself.

See also John 8:31, 32, 20:30, 31, Acts 20:32, Ps 119:11 105, Rom 15:4, 1 Peter 3:15.

I just let ChatGPT make a hermeneutical analysis of John 16:13-14: https://chatgpt.com/share/c09d7e27-6096-4d19-9cbf-5f7387afdca3  As for whether LLMs grasp the significance of any text: Is grasping the significance of a text with the Holy Spirit even necessary for Hermeneutics? I understand that is part of theology etc. but Hermeneutics as far as I understood it, is about getting the meaning out of a text. It is debatable how far LLMs can go, but I don't think we can simply disregard them either.

@telion - that is the point - LLM's do not have, nor do they "understand" any meaning whatsoever.

I think at this point I have to ask: What are your criteria for "understanding" the meaning of a text? Also is it necessary to help with hermeneutics? Refer to the chat I had with ChatGPT: Point out what is wrong with that analysis. Also, why exactly is this question off-topic? It is part of a hermeneutical approach and here you have the opportunity to present the problems and risks with it by giving an example where the AI is clearly wrong. If you want I can open another question regarding an example for inaccuracies that LLMs produce.

@telion - I suggest you examine some of the works of Prof John Searle who deals with the question before LLM's even existed.

LLM sounds like a useful tool, but to depend on it now for a final translation seems like depending on a Tesla to drive itself without supervision.

Conclusion without Trinity presumption: "John 16:13-14 provides a rich theological and practical insight into the role of the spirit of truth. It assures believers of divine guidance into all truth, emphasizing the continuity of Jesus' mission and the glorification of Jesus through the spirit’s work. This passage highlights the role of the spirit as a mediator of divine truth, ensuring the ongoing revelation and deepening understanding of Jesus' teachings for both personal spiritual growth and the broader mission of the church.". https://chatgpt.com/share/3fd834d0-e296-44ea-9891-f2588a93ce56

@RayButterworth - agreed - my point is that the sum and substance of the Bible message is Christ and this can only be understood by the enlightenment of the Spirit.

I think this answer sort of misses the point of what LLMs are and how they function. The model doesn't 'grasp the significance' of anything, and so it's on an equal footing with hermeneutics as it is with cookery instructions. The LLM will generate an answer based on pre-existing content it has collected from elsewhere - i.e. from human authors who have previously exegeted the text, with or without the active work of the Holy Spirit. So if you are a Christian, on balance you could say that a similar proportion of the answer is based on the Spirit's leading to a typical human answer.
